# PHP query not returning data from new SQL column (MAMP)

Tags: php, mysql, database

I needed to simply add a new column to my DB table during development to accommodate a data change, however, my query when ran from my PHP script is not returning the column or data within said new column. My query is as straightforward as it gets `SELECT * FROM time_table ORDER BY date DESC`. It returns all previously existing columns from `time_table`, which leads me to believe there is a caching issue somewhere. I am using MAMP for local development, if that helps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM time ORDER BY date DESC` here table name is `time` or `time_table` ?

Comment: Oops, typo, tablename is `time_table`, edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was a fault of my own.

Moral of the story: Do not forget to update your model(s) after making structure changes to the DB.